# Bash Error When Implementing Java Data Analysis Tools

Tags: linux, bash, unix, jar, gnu

So I am trying to install a set of java tools using BASH for processing large amounts of data.

```
mkdir dataprocessor
cd dataprocessor
wget https://github.com/bigdataprocessor_java_tools/bjt.zip
unzip bjt.zip
```

Now I have the tools successfully unzipped with no issues.  I now go to my bash profile using emacs, so going to my home directory

```
cd home
emacs ~/.bash_profile
```

and then adding a  line:

```
export BJT_JAR=(home/dataprocessor/bjt.jar)
```

Now, when I try and run command:

```
java -jar $BJT_JAR
```

I get the error "invalid or corrupt jarfile".  Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried removing and re-downloading/unzipping the file as well.

Comment: You missed the leading `/` on the path in `BJT_JAR`. Also you don't need (or want) the enclosing `()` on that assignment. They aren't doing anything useful for you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a moron and forgot to log off and log back on again.

Answer (score 1):

did the command "cd home" work and moved you to home directory ?

change:

```
export BJT_JAR=(home/dataprocessor/bjt.jar)
```

to:

```
export BJT_JAR=(${HOME}/dataprocessor/bjt.jar)
```

or

```
export BJT_JAR="${HOME}/dataprocessor/bjt.jar"
```

you will need to re-login or execute the .bash_profile script for changes to take place